# DOMContentLoaded sometimes work and sometimes doesn't while setTimeout usually always work

Tags: javascript

DOMContentLoaded sometimes work and sometimes doesn't while setTimeout usually always work.

For example, the following code works:

```
setTimeout( ()=>{
    let sites = ['mako.co.il'];
    let regex = /\..+/;
    let href = window.location.href;
    for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
        if (href.includes(sites[i])) {
            let domain = sites[i].replace(regex, '');
            document.body.innerHTML =`
                <div style="direction: ltr; position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 999999; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: red">
                  <p style="position: relative; top: 40%; display: block; font-size: 66px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center">
                    Enough with this ${domain} bullshit!
                  </p>
                </div>
          `;
        }
    }
}, 1500);
```

But if instead `setTimeout( ()=>{...}, 1500);` I would use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{...});` it won't.

Why is that?

In both cases I wait a certain time period and then execute the code. What could be the case that after all DOM tree loaded, the code fails?

Comment: "sometimes does and sometimes doesnt work" - can you elaborate? Give us some more specific scenario's as to when what does and does not work. For instance: "The DOMContentLoaded event only works on initial page load and not on consecutive navigation within the website". This helps us narrow down the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code inside DOMContentLoaded event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993676/code-inside-domcontentloaded-event-not-working) | Also this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993676/code-inside-domcontentloaded-event-not-working#comment67265322_39993676

Comment: Sadly I really think I can't, in this case, @SidOfc because if I remember correctly about 2 months ago it worked, and now it didn't. I wish I had more details than that, on this... :| I might recall wrongly, and `DOMContentLoaded` didn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably related to that some embedded resources like images are sometimes loaded from browser’s cache (fast) while sometimes loaded from the web (slowly).

The `document`’s `DOMContentLoaded` event fires after the document is available, but *before* embedded resources like images are loaded.

So you probably just need the `window`’s `load` event instead:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // This code runs after all resources including images are loaded.
}, false);
```

Comment: You mean `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{...});` instead `document` on start? Sadly, it didn't work. Or maybe I didn't understand correct.

Comment: Oh sorry, okay, I should read on the difference between `DOMContentLoaded` and `load` events.

Comment: Thank you Marat. It worked. Just a small note: I wrote `true` in the end (while you wrote `false`) and it worked as well. Is there a particular reason you wrote `false`? Thanks again!

Comment: `false` is the default value of the third parameter that was not always optional and may still be needed in some older browsers. The purpose of the parameter itself is described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).