# How can I resolve this DOMContentLoaded or addEventListener issue?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a finicky issue and may be difficult to figure out. This JavaScript controls the intro, play and stop/start of an mp4 video. Most of the code has to do with the video playback and position of the navigation images and links, and isn't really relevant to this question.

**The problem:** on initial page load, sometimes the canvas div is hidden by the `display:none` in the `<video>` tag and the video start and canvas div is blank. This doesn't happen all the time; it happens less often in Firefox, but most of the time in Chrome. If blank, a mouse click in the canvas div will then show introstill.png image and then you can click to start the video.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the way the function at the end of the script is constructed with `myvideo.init` and maybe breaks `addEventListener`, but I don't know.

I see the issue in both an .html file in localhost and on the live server. I've tried wrapping the whole function in `jQuery('document').ready(function()` with no luck. I've tried disabling caching of the mp4 at the webhost. There are no browser console errors, and no browser add-ons conflicting.

As per [@titus' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77383960/javascript-how-i-can-i-resolve-this-domcontentloaded-or-addeventlistener-issue#comment136422608_77383960): how would I change
`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {` ?

And, I don't know enough JavaScript to strip out the irrelevant code to make a minimal reproducible example of addEventListener or DOMContentLoaded.

```html
<script>

    var myvideo = (function (window) {
        var app = {};
    
        var buttonBg_out = new Image();
        var buttonBg_over = new Image();
        var nextText = new Image();
        var beginText = new Image();
        var startAgain = new Image();
        var introStill = new Image();
        var pauseOverlay = new Image();
        
        var REAL_WIDTH = 656;
        var REAL_HEIGHT = 386;
        var ASPECT_RATIO = REAL_WIDTH / REAL_HEIGHT;
        var SCALE = 1.0;
    
        app.init = function (root) {
        buttonBg_out.src = root + 'button-out.png';
        buttonBg_over.src = root + 'button-over.png';
        nextText.src = root + 'next.png';
        beginText.src = root + 'begin.png';
        startAgain.src = root + 'startagain.png';
        introStill.src = root + 'introstill.png';   
        pauseOverlay.src = root + 'pauseoverlay.png';
    
        var document = window.document;
    
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {          // addEventListener
            var video = document.getElementById('myvid');
            var canvas = document.getElementById('playbackcontainer');
    
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                
            introStill.onload = () => {
            ctx.drawImage(introStill,0,31,introStill.width,introStill.height);
            };
    
            var rescaling = function () {
            SCALE = canvas.clientWidth / REAL_WIDTH;
            setTimeout(rescaling, 10);
            };
            rescaling();
            
            var drawVideo = function () {
            if (video.paused || video.ended) return;
    
            ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            drawButton();
            setTimeout(drawVideo,1); // might fiddle with this timeout;
            };
            
            var button = {x:0,y:0,
                  w:127,
                  h:66,
                  state: buttonBg_out,
                  text: beginText,
                  visible: false
                 };
            
            var localXY = function (e) {
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
            var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
            return {x:x,y:y};
            };
            
            var isOverButton = function (e) {
            var xy = localXY(e);
            var x = xy.x;
            var y = xy.y;
    
            return (x >= (button.x * SCALE) && y >= (button.y * SCALE) &&
                x <= ((button.x + button.w)*SCALE) &&
                y <= ((button.y + button.h)*SCALE));
            };
            
            var drawButton = function () {
            if (button.visible) {
                ctx.drawImage(button.state,
                      button.x ,button.y ,
                      button.w ,button.h );
                
                ctx.drawImage(button.text,
                      (button.x + 14) ,
                      (button.y + 23) ,
                      button.text.width ,
                      button.text.height );
            }
            };
            
            var isOverStartOver = function (e) {
            var xy = localXY(e);
            return xy.x >= 9*SCALE && xy.x <= 92*SCALE && xy.y >= 367*SCALE && xy.y <= 379*SCALE;
            };
            
            var isOverReplayScene = function (e) {
            var xy = localXY(e);
            return xy.x >= 102*SCALE && xy.x <= 186*SCALE && xy.y >= 367*SCALE && xy.y <= 379*SCALE;
            };
            
            var permissionGiven = false;
            
            var currentScene = 0;
            var sceneBounds = [{start:4.583, showButton:13.849,
                    loopStart:15.116, loopEnd:22.183,
                    afterPress:23.416},
                       
                       {start:25.649, showButton:53.416,
                    afterPress: 55.983},
                       
                       {start:58.216, showButton:99.0,
                    afterPress:100.483},
                       
                       {start:103.649, showButton:156.149,
                    afterPress:156.816},
                       
                       {start:159.049, showButton:229.883,
                    loopStart:230.5, loopEnd:236.383,
                    afterPress:242.00}];
            
            video.addEventListener('play', drawVideo, false);
            video.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
            var bounds = sceneBounds[currentScene];
            
            if (video.currentTime >= bounds.showButton) {
                button.visible = true;
                drawButton();
            }
            
            if (bounds.loopEnd != null) { // keep playing
                if (video.currentTime >= bounds.loopEnd) {
                video.currentTime = bounds.loopStart;
                }
            } else if (video.currentTime >= bounds.showButton) {        // pause
                video.pause();
            }
            });
            
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            if (isOverButton(e)) {
                button.state=buttonBg_over;
                drawButton();
            } else {
                button.state=buttonBg_out;
                drawButton();
            }
            });
            
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
            if (!permissionGiven)
            {
                permissionGiven = true;
                video.currentTime = sceneBounds[0].start;
                video.play();
                button.x = 322;
                button.y = 244;
    
            } else {
    
                if (video.paused && currentScene > 0 && currentScene < 4 && !isOverButton(e)) {
                if (isOverStartOver(e)) {
                    video.currentTime = sceneBounds[0].start;
                    button.visible = false;
                    button.x = 322;
                    button.y = 244;
                    button.text = beginText;
                    currentScene = 0;
                    video.play();
                } else if (isOverReplayScene(e)) {
                    button.visible = false;
                    video.currentTime = sceneBounds[currentScene].start;
                    video.play();
                } else {
                    video.play();
                }
    
                } else if (currentScene == 4 && !isOverButton(e)) {
    
                if (isOverStartOver(e)) {
                    button.visible = false;
                    video.currentTime = sceneBounds[currentScene].start;
                    video.play();
                }
    
                } else if (button.visible && isOverButton(e)) { // button was presssed
                
                currentScene = (currentScene +  1) % sceneBounds.length;
                
                if (currentScene == 0)
                {
                    button.text = beginText;
                    video.currentTime = sceneBounds[currentScene].start;
                    button.x = 322;
                    button.y = 244;
                } else {
                    button.text = nextText;
                    button.x = 515;
                    button.y = 304;
                    video.currentTime = sceneBounds[currentScene-1].afterPress;
                }
                
                if (currentScene == 4)
                    button.text = startAgain;
                
                button.visible = false;
                
                video.play();
    
                } else if (video.paused) {
                video.play();
                } else {
                video.pause();
                ctx.drawImage(pauseOverlay,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                }
            }
            });
        });
        };
        return app;
    })(window);
    
    (function(){
    var thevid = document.getElementById("myvid");
    myvideo.init("/path/to/folder/with/images/and/mp4/");
    })();
    
    </script>
    
    <div class="flex-video">
    <video id="myvid" style="display:none;" playsinline>
    <source src="/path/to/folder/with/images/and/mp4/the_video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/></video>
    <canvas id="playbackcontainer" width="656" height="386"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Comment: Most probably the problem is that the `DOMContentLoaded` event was fired before the listener was added, you can prevent that using something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event#checking_whether_loading_is_already_complete)

Comment: @Titus Thanks! That's interesting. I'll have to see if I can figure out the changes I need to make; I don't know Javascript really at all :(

Comment: `thevid` should always be `null` here, but it’s unused. It’s not possible for `DOMContentLoaded` to fire before a synchronous script finishes running, so that’s not it (if the HTML is as shown). Please create a [mre]: “Most of the code has to do with the video playback and position of the navigation images and links, and isn't really relevant to this question” – so remove it and create a new reproduction case that only includes relevant parts

Comment: It’s probably not safe to assume that `window`’s `DOMContentLoaded` will happen before `introStill.onload`, though. (Why draw the video element to a canvas instead of letting the video element display normally, by the way?)

Comment: @Ry- Thanks for the help; but I don't know enough Javascript to accurate strip out the irrelevant code to have a simpler example. I inherited this code and I word has it that it was generated by a Flash to HTML5 converter :( And I don't know why canvas is used.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch What are you trying to do, exactly? Are you aware that by design `<video>`  **cannot** autoplay unless `a. The user has interacted with the website a bit beforehand? Say, he navigated to the video page via a mouse press, and not via typing in a URL` or else `b. The <video> is muted via the "muted" attribute`, or `c. The user clicked on the video`? If you're trying to autoplay a video that doesn't have the `muted` attribute, you'll get inconsistent results where it SOMETIMES works, depending on how much you've interacted with the website during the current visit.

Comment: More information on Autoplaying videos: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#new-behaviors

Comment: + Do you get any errors in your Dev Tools console? It's possible that a different, completely unrelated error can be preventing this JS from even running. Can you give us a screenshot of your console? (F12->"Console"->Refresh the page-> Screenshot)

Comment: @EliezerBerlin Thanks for the info; I'm not trying to autoplay. On initial page load, sometimes the video and canvas divs are blank. This doesn't happen all the time; it happens less often in Firefox, but most of the time in Chrome. A mouse click in the blank canvas div will show the introstill.png and start the video. If the canvas is blank, sometimes a hard refresh will show the introstill.png and then you can click to start the video. I'm only guessing that it's a addEventListener or DOMContentLoaded issue; it could be something else. No console errors.

Comment: **11/4/23**- You said script ```console error Uncaught TypeError: window is undefined``` is this running on a server-side?

Comment: That was trying CodeApacalypse's code in the 11/4/23 edit on localhost; not in my original code above that.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I'm still convinced it's related to Autoplay, because of your symptoms of it working inconsistently. What is the desired behavior? That it show the thumbnail, but not start playing until the user clicks? (Because Autoplay is off?)

Comment: @EliezerBerlin Thanks! Maybe it is related to autoplay. When it loads and works correctly, the thumbnail introstill.png shows, and when the user clicks on it, the video plays; and if the user clicks again, the video pauses and pauseoverlay.png shows until the user clicks again.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch So what I'm understanding is that it's currently working as intended, it's just that sometimes the thumbnail image doesn't display? But other than that, everything is working perfectly?

Comment: @EliezerBerlin That's right; sometimes introstill.png doesn't display, but then clicking in the blank video canvas area will flash the png for an instant and the video will start. After that, the video can be clicked to stop/start. This is why I think it is a possibly a document ready/loaded issue. Happens most often in Chrome, less often in Firefox; localhost or live server doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @EliezerBerlin Well, the bounty expired :( But if you have some ideas to offer, that would be great.

Comment: Nothing productive, I'm afraid. There's GOT to be some kind of message in the `console` when the error occurs. Or if not in the console, maybe in your `network` tab there's a 404 or 403 or something. Check your network tab too, and verify that the `png` file of the thumbnail image downloaded correctly. (Maybe just it failed to download the `.png` file of the thumbnail, or maybe the URL is somehow wrong and therefore it got a 404 error, or something.)

Comment: If you add a console.log() right before `ctx.drawImage(introStill,0,31,introStill.width,introStill.height);` , does the console.log trigger?

Comment: Yea, this is a real puzzle. No errors in the network or Console tabs. All images are 200 status. No 404's. But that's a good idea to add `console.log('breakpoint')` ; I should have thought of that. When introStill.png does not load (on initial page load or hard refresh), no log; when it loads normally, the log appears. Same as when the console.log is added right below `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {`

Comment: If the `console.log` isn't working, it should be pretty easy to create a simplified reproducible test case. Maybe create some `console.logs`, delete everything else that isn't `console.log`, and then post a simplified version of the question, saying, "Hey, my console.logs aren't working." (At the very least, this should help you start to narrow down what the possible causes could be.) Though, honestly, if that's how the console.logs are working, then it DOES sound like it's a problem with `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'` firing BEFORE your JS runs, so your  code never triggers.

Comment: So if it's caused by your JS being loaded after `DOMContentLoaded` already happened, so the code never runs, maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993724/5243309 would solve it.

Answer (score -1):

If you give your `<script>` tag the `defer` keyword (`<script defer></script>`), it will be run after all of the elements on the DOM have been loaded.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer): Warning: This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect.

Comment: You could also try putting the `script` block at the end of the body (After all of your content).